# confusion related to numerically greatest term

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

So I have derived the formula for the numerically greatest term of the following expression 
$$(a+b)^n$$

It is given by taking $T_r$ and $T_{r+1}$ and using the fact that
$$\frac{T_{r+1}}{T_r} \geq 1$$ (or reciprocal depending on "which" r we need)

where $T_r$ is the r'th term of the binomial expansion of $(a+b)^n$ and r goes from $1$ to $(n+1)$

So basically $T_r = \hspace{0.1cm} ^nC_r \hspace{0.1cm}a^{n-r}\hspace{0.1cm}b^r$ in the expansion of $(a+b)^n$

*Important : Note that we are supposed to expand $(a+b)^n$ first and then put in values of a and b*

So finally the formula is :
$$r\geq \frac{1+n}{1+ |\frac{a}{b}|}$$

we then simply find the $T_r$ which would be the NGT. Done !

My confusion is which to take as 'a' and which as 'b'. Wouldn't they be interchangeable ?
Or maybe ... does the result apply for both 'a' and 'b' (any order) ?
(But no it doesn't !!)

Now what is the correct formula ?

for a quick example refer this Q/A : 
[1] [What is the numerically greatest or magnitude wise greatest term in the expansion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2592731/what-is-the-numerically-greatest-or-magnitude-wise-greatest-term-in-the-expansio/2592742#2592742)

[2] [Greatest term in the expansion $(2+3x)^9$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2350323/greatest-term-in-the-expansion-23x9)

Okay . . . revisiting my question again after going through the comments, here is the **question which I would like answered**:

I understood that my formula was wrong. We are not supposed to open up $(a+b)^n$ just as it is. We are required to factor out either a or b after which we end up with the binomial of $(1+x)^n$. Then again applying $T_{r+1} \geq T_{r}$ we get $$r \geq \frac{(1+n)|x|}{(1+|x|)}$$

Here's the issue : **Which exactly do i factor out: a or b?**

Comment: It would really help if you define precisely what $T_r$ is.

Comment: I don't understand anything you are saying!  You have $(a+ b)^n$ and ask fo r the "numerically largest term".  What "terms"? What are  a and b?  If they are numbers then a+ b  and $(a+ b)^n$ are numbers and there are NO "terms".  If they are not numbers then the terms are NOT "numerical".  Then you start talking about $T_r$ and $T_{r+1}$ but have not said what they are!

Comment: i thought people might be familiar with the binomial theorem. sorry ! i will edit

Comment: Since $a$ and $b$ occur symmetrically in $(a+b)^n$ but not in your formula, your formula cannot possibly be correct.

Comment: @saulspatz what about this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dT4w3OBk5No&t=174s

Comment: I doubt you've transcribed it correctly, but if you have, then the video is wrong.

Comment: ig i found my mistake ! It lies in the part where i open (a+b)^n casually. I am not supposed to do that. Rather, i should factor out one of a or b to get it in the form of (1+x)^n and then apply the formula :  r >=  (1+n)|x| / (1+|x|) which is also given here on brilliant - https://brilliant.org/wiki/jee-binomial-theorem/

Comment: But i dont know why i am needed to factor it out. If i do it with a and b i get the formula as given in the question but if i go with b and a i get another close formula...